# sending mail with google apps script doesn't show my correct name as the sender

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

When I send an email from my gmail account (info@workspaceEHR.com) manually, the sender name seen by the recipient is my first name, as I set it in my gmail settings. But when I send an email with Google Apps Script (`GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subjectLine, emailBody)`) the receiver sees the sender name as "info". Anyone know why this happens or how to set it so that the sender name comes out right?

This is a code I am sharing with others, so I need a generic solution, not one in which I manually type my first name into the code in some setting. Thanks!

Comment: Does this help: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options  Look at optional parameters

Comment: Well, one of the parameters is "name": the name of the sender of the email (default: the user's name). So if the default is my name, why is it coming up as "info" when in my account (both gmail and general google) my first name is listed correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Recommendation: Set display name of the Sender**

As per replication, if the `name` parameter is not set, the default value shows the whole email address of the sender.

Sample output:

[image]

However, if you want to set a different name rather than showing the sender's email address, you can use the `name` parameter to define the display name that you want.

Here's a sample code:

```
function sendingEmail(){


MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: <insert email address>,
        subject: 'test',
        name: 'display name'
      });
}
```

Sample output:

[image]

**Reference:**

- [Gmailapp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)